# Sending php session variable using scriptData in Uploadify

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload, uploadify

I am using uploadify to to upload a file and I want to store it in a folder depending on the value of a radio button. I have multiple folders and I want the user to select one of the folders using a radio button and then upload files.

Using the value of the radio button, I will decide the folder and I also want to append the user id to the uploaded file. How can I send the value of radio button #type.val() and _SESSION['id'] to the uploadify.php

I tried doing this but it doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/uploads/operatingSystem',
    'auto'      : true,
    'scriptData': {'type':''},
    'onSelectOnce' : function(event,data) {
        $("#file_upload").uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'type' : ('#topic').val()});

  });
});
</script>
```

In this I still do not know how to give the session id because this does not work

```
'scriptData': {'type':'', 'id':''},
 'onSelectOnce' : function(event,data) {
     $("#file_upload").uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'type' : ('#topic').val(), 'id' : <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?> });
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally it should work but with my PHP 5.3.8 if I want to use the session variable it's spelled $_SESSION an not _SESSION. Maybe a language problem?

Comment: No that is not the thing, I have used $_SESSION only. When I use this script the the styling of the uploadify button disappears. I think there is something wrong with the script that I have written

Comment: O.k. so it's not a spelling issue but how can you make inline PHP in JS?

Comment: I did not get what you asked??? Is there no way I can send a PHP session variable in uploadify, further I am unable to send the button value also

Comment: You have 2 choices: 1. inline PHP or 2. Or you pick the $_SESSION variable before you attach this code to file_upload. But uploadify is a PHP script you don't need to pass a $_SESSION variable to a PHP script. Can you clarify a bit your question?

Comment: Actually the thing is that I am unable to access the $_SESSION variable in the uploadify php script that's why I need to send it somehow from here

Comment: I don't understand either. Maybe there isn't a session at all? In that case you need to create a session with session_start() in your php script or uploadify.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, we recently switched our development server to 5.3 and all upload scripts stopped working (using the $_SESSION var which i pass through the post data.-> scriptData). when i switch back to 5.2 everything works like charm. Something is not configured properly, and I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pass sessions by formData. Here is an example code:

**JS Code:**

```
$('#file_upload).uploadify({
    formData : { '<?php echo session_name();?>' : '<?php echo session_id();?>' }
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$session_name = session_name();
if (!isset($_POST[$session_name])) {
    exit;
} else {
    session_id($_POST[$session_name]);
    session_start();
}
```

I hope it'll be helpful.